# Is there any special reason for STOSB to use extra segment?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, memory-segmentation

I have read that `STOSB` functions like this:

```
ES:[DI] <-- AL
```

If `DF = 0` increment `DI` else decrement `DI`.

- So why `STOSB` doesn't change `DS:[DI]`?
- Is there a special purpose for using extra segment?
- In most string instructions we use extra segment. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So why STOSB doesn't change DS:[DI]

Because this definition would collide with the use of `LODSB` which already uses `DS:[SI]`. Using a separate segment register gives you more flexibility.

> Is there a special purpose for using extra segment?

Yes. You can transfer bytes between segments easily while processing them. For example, you can use a `LODSB` loading `AL` from `DS:[SI]`, modify `AL` and then store it to a different segment, the *Extra Segment*, with `STOSB` using `ES:[DI]`. In 8086 with its 16-bit segment size and a 20-bit address space this is really useful.

Another instruction illustrating the use is the `REP MOVSB` instruction which copies a sequence of bytes (with its length in `CX`) from `DS:[SI]` to `ES:[DI]`.

(If you don't need to examine each byte as you copy it, you'd simply use `rep movsb` or `rep movsw` for better performance than `lods`/`stos` in a loop.)

> In most string instructions we use extra segment. why?

Well, not in most, but maybe roughly in half of them. Using another segment register gives you the advantage of quick access to different segments - you are not limited to processing data only in one 64KB segment and do not have to change the `DS` register before each access to a different segment.

`stos` and `movs` write `es:[di]`, which makes sense because `DI` is the "destination index" register.

`cmps` and `scas` read from `es:[di]`, which is maybe surprising for `scas` because it only has one memory operand so you might expect it to read from `ds:[si]` like `lods`.  Especially because [SCASB](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/scas:scasb:scasw:scasd) sets flags from `AL - [mem]`, not the other way around, so it's like a `cmp` where memory is the right operand (source), not left (destination).  Like `cmp al, es:[di]`.

Perhaps the architect of the 8086's instruction set imagined a use-case of a loop that does `lods` and `scas` to implement `strcmp` between segments.

Comment: For most of the string instructions, ES:DI (DI -> destination index) is the store address, with SCASB/W being the exception that is uses ES:DI to scan (read) memory for a matching byte / word (in 16 bit mode).

Comment: If your length is ECX (not just CX), your addresses will also be 32-bit DS:[ESI], not SI.  There might be a combination of prefixes which could achieve 16-bit address-size and 32-bit counter size in some mode, but I'm not sure.  It certainly wouldn't be normal, though.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: No, both the address size (`di` vs `edi` or `si` vs `esi`) and counter size (`cx` vs `ecx`) are determined by the same ASIZE quality, ie a16 or a32. I assume this also holds true for a64.

Comment: @ecm: Interesting, that's probably why the `loop` instruction uses address-size instead of operand-size to control ECX vs. RCX.  Yes, https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rep:repe:repz:repne:repnz confirms that in 64-bit mode, a 67h prefix will use ECX, ESI, EDI, instead of the default RCX, RSI, RDI.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: Using a32 in a 64-bit code segment, I wonder whether the counter and index register updates zero-extend into the 64-bit registers like as if they were explicit 32-bit operands?

Comment: @ecm: I'd be shocked if they didn't zero-extend.  But since you mention it I tested: `a32 loop .loop` does truncate RCX, for this test case: `mov rcx, 0x1000000002` / `.loop: a32 loop .loop`.  So I'd be even more shocked if updates to EDI and ESI didn't zero-extend.  That would be the only case where x86-64 hardware would even need to merge a new low-32 into a 64-bit register instead of zero-extending.